# How to get the version of the app installed in the simulator from terminal

Tags: swift, xcode, appium, appium-ios, xcrun

Is there command to get the version of the app installed in the simulator, I am looking for any xcode commands or any other command through which i can fetch the app version

Answer (score 2):

Let try:

```
defaults read $(xcrun simctl get_app_container booted your.app.bundle.identifier)/Info CFBundleVersion
```

Comment: I run it successfully, how many simulator you're running?

Comment: you could try to run sub-command first: xcrun simctl get_app_container booted your.app.bundle.identifier

Comment: remember to change your.app.bundle.identifier with your

Comment: Only 1 simulator is running and i have replaced the bundle id:   (xcrun simctl get_app_container booted myBundleId)/Info CFBundleVersion.   I am using this command please check am i missing something?

Comment: be sure to use quotes
`defaults read "$(xcrun simctl get_app_container booted your.app.bundle.identifier)"/Info` if your app name contains spaces